# Flask app not working when deployed on Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask

My Flask app is running smoothly on `localhost` but it doesn't work when I deploy it to heroku. Also the `heroku logs` are not giving much informative errors. Here's my log

```
`1:16:23.145279+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172177+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2016-07-09T21:16:23.145282+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-07-09T21:16:23.145299+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named comprehensive_search
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172733+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172424+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172842+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2016-07-09T21:16:23.145289+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 13, in <module>
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172469+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2016-07-09T21:16:23.145285+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172910+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 231, in handle_chld
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172601+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2016-07-09T21:16:23.173016+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 506, in reap_workers
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172317+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 192, in run
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172990+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2016-07-09T21:16:23.145298+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
2016-07-09T21:16:23.173286+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2016-07-09T21:16:23.172490+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 218, in run
2016-07-09T21:16:23.145742+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-09 21:16:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2016-07-09T21:16:23.983452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-09T21:16:23.968188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-09T21:16:43.235185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=notes-in-short.herokuapp.com request_id=494cdb87-7e25-4340-992d-19c6a32b7e99 fwd="203.100.73.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-09T21:20:15.679536+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/upload" host=notes-in-short.herokuapp.com request_id=19dad39c-d05c-4130-8f69-3fff5b043d19 fwd="27.60.87.185" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-09T21:22:26.694762+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/upload" host=notes-in-short.herokuapp.com request_id=85e4de0c-175b-45b7-8a41-34f93c1a1940 fwd="203.100.73.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-09T21:22:31.702677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=notes-in-short.herokuapp.com request_id=afb6d01b-b0ba-4379-a9a4-db4738eb3883 fwd="203.100.73.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
`
```

I've tried a lot but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong. Could you help me debug?

Comment: What's comprehensive_search? Your code? Third party code?

Comment: comprehensive_search is a directory I cloned and I'm using it in my app

Comment: Is it checked into your git repository and pushed to heroku?

Comment: How do I know if both repositories are pushed to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Your comprehensive_search module is not being pushed to heroku. It probably hasn't been committed to your local git repository.

You can tell from the heroku side by creating a one off bash dyno:

```
heroku run bash
```

You'll get a remote shell and you can issue linux commands to see whether the module code is where you think it should be.

From there you can make sure you've checked the directory into git properly.